# TileStache RuntimeError: Sqlite Plugin does not exist

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu-14.04, mapnik, tilestache

I run TileStache 1.50.1 with success rendering different providers but have a problem when using mapnik styles. Turning on debug I get this error with Werkzeug:

> "RuntimeError: Sqlite Plugin: /opt/TileStache/styles/test.sqlite does
>   not exist  encountered during parsing of layer 'testGeometry' in Layer
>   at line 20 of '/opt/TileStache/styles/test.xml'"

Does this mean that Mapnik doesn't find Sqlite Plugin? Or could it have to do something with sqlite spatialite extension I compiled on this machine?

I run Mapnik 2.2 standard package on Ubuntu 14.04 (libmapnik2.2) and mapnik sqlite plugin file exists at /usr/lib/mapnik/2.2/input/sqlite.input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime error just comes from a wrong route to sqlite file. Sorry, my fault.